# How to expose an EJB as a web service that is not transactional?

Tags: ejb, jax-ws, java-ee-6

I have an EJB (coded using Java EE 6 annotations) that is defined as follows:

```
@Stateless
@WebService
public class SecurityWebService {

    public void registerUser(RegistrationRequest request) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that this EJB is also exposed as a web service. However, I am running into an issue with the generated web service. The WSDL generated by my container (GlassFish) contains WS-Atomic Transaction policies because a stateless session bean by default is transactional (see details [here](http://java.net/jira/browse/WSIT-649)). Unfortunately my .NET client is choking on the WSDL because it does not understand WS-AT policies.

So what I really want is a nice-clean web service that is not transactional, but the associated EJB should be transactional (it has to insert records in the database). How do I do this? The only approach I can think of is to create a "normal" web service that passes all its calls to an EJB like this - not elegant at all:

```
@WebService
public class SecurityWebService {

    @Inject
    private SecurityService securityService;

    public void registerUser(RegistrationRequest request) {
        securityService.registerUser(request);
    }
}

@Stateless
public class SecurityService {

    public void registerUser(RegistrationRequest request) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there a better way?

Thanks.

Naresh

Comment: Why is your solution not elegant? This is a clean separation of responsibilities. The non-transactional webservice has different responsibilites than the transactional EJB. It also allows you to change things around later easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can try annotating the method:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
```

or

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
```

Dunno if the web service will pick that up or not, but it's worth a shot.

Edit for comment:

Did you try REQUIRES_NEW? They may well not propagate back out to the web service.

Otherwise, yea, you'll be stuck facading the transactional part with the non-transactional web service.

Comment: Well, that indeed removes WS-AT policies from the WSDL, but the side-effect is that my EJB has now become non-transactional. As stated above, this bean needs to perform database transactions so it has to be transactional.

Comment: Then turn your transaction to be a bean managed transaction. Get the transaction object from your entitymanager, begin the transaction, do your db work, commit the transaction. Just don't forget to annotate you web service EJB that you will use bean managed transactions